# Adding FilterExpression in JasperReports with help of Java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am developing a tool in Java which enable to make some automations in JasperReports (automatically printing, setting parameters etc..) I use mostly JasperReport library. Now I have to set Filter Expression using Java code. I know how to prepare parameters, I make this in this way:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("filter", "where name like '%.'");
```

and then, I pass this parameters while generating PDF report:

```
JasperPrint pdf = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);
```

If there is such a simple way to modify parameters, I guess there is similar way to modify filter expression. I've been searching this for a long time but I found nothing.

Comment: `I need to add new Filter Expression to my Jasper report using Java code.` - What do you mean?

Comment: Mannually, you can add Filter Expression to your report. For instance something like this: `$F{NAME}.contains( "USP") ||$F{NAME}.contains("O")`. In the source of report, it look like this: `<filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}.contains( "USP" )||
 $F{NAME}.contains("O")]]></filterExpression>` And my job is to set these condition in a java code

Comment: Are you taking about JavaBean based datasource?

Comment: Exactly, I mean JasperReport library. I guess that if I can set parameters using this library, there is also option to set filter expression but i don't know how. Any method can be good, but only if it can be done automaticaly ( using code)

Comment: You can filter collection, for example with help of Guava: [Filtering a list of JavaBeans with Google Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8636502/876298) or with Stream API: [Java 8 Lambda filter by Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30012295/876298)

Comment: But I can't filter collection, I have to filter data in report. Report has data and i need to set a condition to filter this data

Comment: Please try to setup a [mcve] its hard to understand what you need to filter, how you need to filter it and what is your expected output. Maybe a printWhenExpression on the detail band is your solution, maybe not..

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report filter expression (or any other expression for that matter) can only be set/changed in `JasperDesign` objects (see the `setFilterExpression` method).  The `JasperDesign` object would have to be recompiled into a `JasperReport`.

An alternative to the filter expression is the `JRParameter.FILTER` builtin parameter, which takes as value a `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DatasetFilter` instance.  JasperReports includes a `DatasetFilter` implementation called `FieldFilter` which is used internally for interactive filtering, but it might not suite your needs, in which case you would need to write your own `DatasetFilter` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a database connection, I can't see no better way then to filter in query.

This limits data that needs to transferred from database and iterated on, hence increased performance and decreased memory usage.

Note, you are passing the whole query using `$P!()`, I probably would have preferred to pass only values using prepared statement and set up query in jasper report expression with `$P()` to understand the difference see [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871042/jasperreports-passing-parameters-to-query)

Another solution if you are not able to filter in query, is to load your data in beans, filter it then pass the resulting `List` as a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html)